# Dielectric question

Tags: copper-pipe, galvanic-corrosion, brass-fitting

I'm replumbing a home, and I have a quick question of when/where to use a dielectric fitting. The water main is coming through a bedroom, outside the interior wall. Starts galvanized from floor and goes to brass shut-off valve about midway. Trying to replace the easier galvanized with pex, but I want to avoid the UV exposure on pex, so completing the bedroom part of the run with copper until it gets to the attic.

So the entire run will be galvanized --> brass fitting (shut-off valve) --> copper --> pex.  I know I need a dielectric fitting here, but would it be between the galvanized and brass, or brass and copper? Thanks

Comment: A picture of where the water line comes in would probably be helpful, because your description has me lost.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm out of town for the week, so I can't take a photo.  But I guess, to simplify and assuming I can't remove the galvanized, where in a galvanized to brass to copper plumbing run do I need to put a dielectric fitting? Thanks

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eqKsYw-2cI

Comment: between steel and copper/brass

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5thvA9dsQmQ